# How to ignore the middle of a string in a regular expression

Tags: qt, qregularexpression

I have a command string in which the middle part should be ignored.

Example:

> settings:volume:save

Using QRegularExpression, I need an expression that returns `true` as soon as the first part of the command contains "*settings*", and the last part contains "*save*". The part in the middle does not matter.

I tried the below, but it does not work:

```cpp
command = "settings:volume:save";
QRegularExpression regex("(^settings\..*_save$)");
if (regex.match(command).hasMatch())
    //match code
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe don't use regexp and do like:

```
const auto options = command.split(':');
if (options.size() == 3 && options.first() == "settings" && options.last() == "save")
{

}
```

If you are fan on regexp, use:

```
QRegularExpression regex("^settings(.*)save$");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you test the following:

```cpp
QRegularExpression regex("(^settings\..*_save$)");
```

using:

```
qDebug()<<regex.pattern();
```

You will get this output:

```cpp
"(^settings..*_save$)"
```

- `\.` will be recognized as a literal dot (`.`).
- `_` will be recognized as a literal unederscore (`_`).

That regular expression will match strings that start with "*settings.*", followed by any characters (except for a newline), and ending with "_save".

It would match this for example:

> settings.somestring_save

To get an expression that matches strings starting with "*settings*", followed by any characters (except for a newline), and ending with "*save*", you could use the following regular expression:

```
^settings.*save$
```

Here is how it works:

- `^settings`: insures the string starts with "*settings*".
- `.*`: allows any characters except for a newline, repeated 0-n times.
- `save$`: insures the string ends with "*save*".

Example:

```cpp
QString command = "settings.SOMESTRING_save";
QString command1 = "settings:volume:save";
QString command2 = "settingsANOTERHString123......save";

QRegularExpression regex("^settings.*save$");

qDebug()<<regex.match(command);
qDebug()<<regex.match(command1);
qDebug()<<regex.match(command2);
```

This outputs:

```
QRegularExpressionMatch(Valid, has match: 0:(0, 24, "settings.SOMESTRING_save"))
QRegularExpressionMatch(Valid, has match: 0:(0, 20, "settings:volume:save"))
QRegularExpressionMatch(Valid, has match: 0:(0, 34, "settingsANOTERHString123......save"))
```

For more specific explanation, you can use online regex testing websites.